# Absolute-positioned div scrolls inside absolute-positioned parent

Tags: html, css

I have an absolute-positioned div with two children -- an absolute-positioned div and a static div which will scroll inside the parent. It looks like this:

```
<div class='frame'>
  <div class='absolute-contents'>This should stay put.</div>
  <div class='static-contents'>This should scroll under it.</div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```css
.frame {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.absolute-contents {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: .9;
  padding: 40px;
}

.static-contents {
  margin: 24px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 3000px;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

I have the absolute child constrained to the edges of the parent, so why does it still scroll, and how can I make it stay put?

Example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wqZxXG

Comment: Have you tried `position: fixed;` yet?

Comment: Yes. But I want it fixed within the parent, rather than the whole window.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I resolved by putting the element I wanted to scroll in an absolute-positioned div with `overflow-y: scroll` like so:

```
<div class='frame'>
  <div class='fix-me'></div>
  <div class='scroll-me'>
    <div class='long-content'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And styling like this:

```
.frame {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.scroll-me {
  background-color: orange;
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.fix-me {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: purple;
}

.long-content {
  width: 480px;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 4000px;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Pen here: https://codepen.io/dustinlocke/pen/vJMzpK

Comment: Looks like you got it sorted with extra markup, similar to the question linked in my answer. Nice job!

Answer (score 5):

You should adjust your child div to use `position: fixed` if you do not want it to move. `position: absolute` just tells a div that its *initial* position should be determined absolutely. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33132765/2756409) for more info on `position: fixed` and a similar scenario to yours.

Set the `.frame` div to `position: relative` (or a parent of `.frame`) for this to work. This will set the `position: fixed` child to be fixed within the `position: relative` parent of `.frame`.

You will need to adjust the positioning amounts (top, bottom, left, right) to account for the different stacking contexts.

Something like this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/brJxVW

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
}

.frame {
  background-color: green;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(100vw - 80px);
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.absolute-contents {
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  right: 40px;
  bottom: 40px;
  z-index: 9999;
  opacity: .9;
  margin: 40px;
}

.big-contents {
  margin: 24px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class='frame'>
    <div class='absolute-contents'>This should stay fixed in the green frame. Why is it scrolling?</div>
    <div class='big-contents'>This should scroll under it.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your pen fixes the child div within the entire window, rather than just the `.frame` element and scrolls the whole body. I'd like to scroll only the elements within the green `.frame` and fix the `.absolute-content` within that green `.frame`

Comment: @DustinRichardLocke From your demo the .frame was the only thing in the document. I'll make an update when I get home later; adding some surrounding realistic elements to your demo would be helpful for me as well.