# Position fixed doesn't apply margin?

Tags: html, css

I want a box that has margin. But position fixed don't seems to contain in my App class?

```
   <div className="App">
      <div className="box">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      </div>
    </div>


.box {
  position: fixed;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-benz-93zp3z?file=/src/App.js

is there any other way to achieve full screen with margin except with fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling to understand your question, but it appears as if you're struggling with applying a margin to your `.box`. You can not apply a margin to a fixed element.
Source: [Why isn't my margin working with position: fixed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132586/why-isnt-my-margin-working-with-position-fixed)

Comment: forget about position: fixed; how do you fill the entire page with margin?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but you can probably do it by creating 1px element then applying a 100vh and 100vw margin to it.