# position absolute not working with margin top properly

Tags: html, css

I have a layout including Header section which is fixed on top, Body section, and Side Menu which is on the right side(please refer to image below). It seems that `margin-top` not working with `position:absolute` properly. Could anybody explain why?

It works as expected when

- removing `position: relative;` from `.container` css class or
- changing `margin-top` to `padding-top` in `.container .body`  css class

### Expected layout

[image]

### Actual layout

[image: [actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTZBx.png)]

## issue code

### html

```html
<div className={styles.container}>
  <div className={styles.header}>Header Section</div>
  <div className={styles.body}>Body Section</div>
  <div className={styles.menu}>Side Menu</div>
</div>
```

### css

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .header {
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.container .body {
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.container .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

Comment: Just a quick thought: when you are applying margin-top to body class, the whole container is pushed down below the fixed header.
Maybe answers from this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33132586/why-isnt-my-margin-working-with-position-fixed

Comment: @mrsagar105 not clear.... why martin-top impacts the absolute container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finanly I found out the root cause. When adding `position:relative` to parent div and `margin-top` to child div, the real top of the parent is the same as child's top, that is to say, the top in my case is "20px" rather than "0", this is why side menu div looks wired.

If removing "position:relative" from parent div, the position:fix positions to the viewport in terms of html, the position of side menu works as expected.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/why-margin-on-child-element-moves-the-parent-element-in-css/

```
If the parent element has no padding or border, and the child element has a top margin, then the child element’s margin collapses with the parent element’s margin, causing the parent element to move along with the child element.
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because you are using `position: fixed` for the `.header` element. That makes your Header section fixed on top and your `container` element starts below it.

For more context to how `fixed`, `absolute` and `relative` positioning work:

- **fixed**: positions an element relative to the viewport, **regardless of whether it is nested inside other elements or not**
- **relative**: positions an element relative to its normal position in the page flow.
- **absolute**: positions an element relative to its parent element. The parent element should have the style `position: relative`, else it will be positioned relative to the viewport (the OG parent element)

**So**, your `.header` element appears is like that because it has a higher stacking context than `.container` element. **Even though it is inside `.container`**, it will still be positioned after the fixed element.

**So to fix the issue: remove `position: fixed` from your `.header` class**

Hope this helps you understand the concept of positioning better!✨

Comment: .header div with position:fixed is positioning to the viewport right? why container element starts below it?

Comment: Yes, elements are `fixed` is positioned relative to the viewport but they also overrides the layering structure because they have a higher stacking context than `relative` elements. 
**so even though** you have *.header* inside the *.container* element, the *.container* element has a `relative` position so it will be positioned **after** the `fixed` element

Comment: But removing `position: fixed` worked for you, correct?

Answer (score 0):

So there are a few things going on here.

1. The reason it works when you remove `position: relative;` from `.container` is that then the absolute positioning is set to the viewport, not an element.
2. It does work if you removed the `position: fixed;` from the `.header` element. I'd want to know why this is fixed, and if the menu element is always going to be in the header. If it is, I would consider changing the mark up (see below). If the menu isn't always going to be in the header, I would consider using `position: sticky;` on the `.header` element if you need it to stay at the top. Though you could still have some issues positioning the menu on top without putting it in the header.
3. If you removed the `margin-top` on the `.body` element the `.menu` item will move to the correct space, but now the `.body` content is below the `.header`. If you added `padding-top` to the `.container` it would offset the height of the header and allow you to position the `.menu` (shown in first snippet). This is still going to cause a problem when the page scrolls.

The real issue is that you're mixing `fixed` and `absolute` positioning. Using `position: fixed;` fixes an element to the viewport, not to an ancestor. So you're `.header` won't scroll, but the `.menu` will. Even if you got it to line up with one of these methods, you'd still watch the `.menu` fly off the header when the page scrolls.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.container .header {
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.container .menu {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header Section</div>
  <div class="menu">Side Menu</div>
  <div class="body">Body Section</div>
</div>
```

I think you should consider updating the mark up. If you did, you wouldn't have to be fighting positioning like this. If you want the header to be fixed, sticky, or static (scroll) then it would just work and the menu would be where you needed it to be. Then you could use something like flexbox to layout the header element while leaving the `.body` to scroll as needed. It would look something like this:

```css
/* make it a little easier to work with widths */
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 40px;
  /* fix for initial load to be below fixed header */
}

.container {
  position: relative;
}

.container .header {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
  display: flex;
  /* use flexbox to layout the header */
  height: 40px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* content on the left / menu on the right */
  padding: 8px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.container .menu {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}

.container .body {
  padding: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">Header Section
    <div class="menu">Side Menu</div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <h1>Body Section</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <h2>This Page Scrolls</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat nobis eaque provident ullam vel sapiente soluta repellat, fugit est, itaque, molestiae culpa reprehenderit autem optio! Dolore cupiditate rerum odio voluptate. Sed nesciunt quod est
      voluptas optio velit. Provident, soluta quaerat praesentium commodi, quia expedita laudantium esse veniam, hic iusto voluptates?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```